# How can I use OPA in server mode with dynamic data?

Tags: opa, rego

I have an event-based system where the input data changes with each event (it's a payload in the event).  The rego rule(s) are static for our purposes.

I run the server like this from command line:

`./opa run --server --set=default_decision=example/allow ./example.rego`

My rego looks like:

```
pacakge example

default python3 = false
python3 {
  pythonVersion := regex.split("python", input.runtime)[1]
  to_number(pythonVersion) >= 3.0
}
```

My input json is dynamic but contains a field 'python'.

Once the server is up I'm trying to call it like this:

`curl localhost:8181/v1/data/example/python3 -i -d @input.json -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

This gives me an error:
`{"result":false,"warning":{"code":"api_usage_warning","message":"'input' key missing from request"}}`

How can I fix this?  I can run this non-server mode with same rego/input.json like this: `./opa eval --data example.rego --input input.json "data.example.python3"`
This gives me a correct "true" response.

Answer (score 0):

The v1 API requires that you wrap the `input` attribute in the request body, so your input.json data needs to look something like:

```json
{
  "input": {
    "attribute_1": "value",
    "attribute_2": "value"
  }
}
```